# Ctrl/Cmd + D results in uneven spacing and images won't snap properly

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

The object below is clip masked. Then, I wanted to add a circle under each lighter-navy bar. 
But, here I ran into problems. 
First, the circle I made will never snap to the rectangle.
Second, ctrl/cmd + D to copy objects in equal spacing eventually results in uneven spacing, even though the first and second object is perfectly placed.

What is possibly wrong here?

Comment: I've done it many times.. if the spacing is uneven, then the original copy was **not** located correctly. It may have *looked* correct, but it wasn't. A **blend** in this instance may be more accurate.

Comment: @Scott weird since I even used the guidelines... how would you recommend using blend?

Comment: The circles are all spaced evenly, it's your object sin the clipping mask that aren't even.

Comment: Blend: position first object, position last object.. create blend with steps you need. Spacing is always even. Just my preference. I've gotten into the habit of using blends whenever I'm considering Cmd+D more than twice.

Comment: Also: You can align the first and the last circle, then select all circles and adjust the spaces in the Align panel.